# How to send POST headers with CasperJS' download function?

Tags: javascript, post, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm having trouble trying to POST data w/ headers via CasperJS [`download`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#download) function.

I can get it to post without headers, just when I add headers it appears those never get sent.

```
casper.then(function() {
  this.download(
    "path/to/file/posting/to",
    "path/to/file/saved/locally",
    "POST",
    // this is the part im stuck on
    // this will post, but how do I add headers to this post?
    "mydata=part1&mydata2=part2"
  );
});
```

When I use `casper.open()` I can do a POST and add JSON with both headers and data objects, but it seems not to be the case with download

Anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PhantomJS' [`page.customHeaders`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/custom-headers.html) property to set custom headers for all requests. This also works for POST requests and the `download()` function.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/f3332f2df42114eade13) is a proof-of-concept tested with CasperJS 1.1-beta3 and PhantomJS versions 2.0.1 and 1.9.7.